# Nginx reverse proxy to apache server, redirection gives 404

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, http-status-code-404, nginx-reverse-proxy, springboot

I have this setup with angular and spring boot project having nginx reverse proxy to apache for serving angular application and embedded server for spring boot reverse proxied through nginx. Now I am loading angular alright but when it comes to making request to spring boot server it gives a 404. I tried to curl the `localhost:8085/api/hello`, it works, or exposing localhost to public through tunnelling,
it works fine. I am missing something in configuration only.

Nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen       154.62.107.99:80 default;
    server_name  _;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/154.62.107.99.log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://154.62.107.99:8080;
   }
   location /api/ {

        # Simple requests
      if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
         add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  "*";
      }


     proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8085/;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
   }
}

server {
    listen      154.62.107.99:443 ssl http2;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate      /usr/local/hestia/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/hestia/ssl/certificate.key;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/154.62.107.99_https.log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_https.log debug;

   # return 301 http://$host$request_uri;

    location / {
      #  root /var/www/document_errors/;

       # Handle preflight requests (OPTIONS)
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  "*";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
            return 200;
        }

        # Handle other requests
        # Add any additional configuration for handling other requests

        # Redirect other requests
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /error/ {
        alias /var/www/document_errors/;
    }
}
```

here I am trying to redirect all request with `/` to apache server running on `8080`. I need to redirect all request with `/api/` to my spring boot server.

I doubt it this reverse proxy things is even working. Here are few observations:

1. Stopping nginx server causes site not to load, hence request is being served from there.
2. Stopping apache server give internal server error
3. for location `/` when I comment out the line `proxy_pass http://154.62.107.99:8080` , it still loads the frontend, which is surprising because I though I was redirecting request to apache from nginx. I don't understand how this is happening.

Update::

This is my apache2 configuration

```
Listen 154.62.107.99:8443
Listen 154.62.107.99:8080
<VirtualHost 154.62.107.99:8080>
    ServerName 154.62.107.99
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    Alias /error/ /var/www/document_errors/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 154.62.107.99:8443>
    ServerName 154.62.107.99
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    Alias /error/ /var/www/document_errors/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile         /usr/local/hestia/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile      /usr/local/hestia/ssl/certificate.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Now content of dist folder are not at /var/www/html, it just contains a success file. Now when I stop the apache2 , I get internal server error and page doesn't loads, but angular project for sure is not being served from here in apache2.

It has another configuration file in `/domains` directory which correctly configures the Document root.

```
<VirtualHost 154.62.107.99:8080>

    ServerName nirbhaysingh.dev
    ServerAlias www.nirbhaysingh.dev
    ServerAdmin info@nirbhaysingh.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/nirbhaysingh.dev.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/nirbhaysingh.dev.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/nirbhaysingh.dev.error.log

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/apache2.forcessl.conf*

    <Directory /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm-nirbhaysingh.dev.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/nirbhaysingh.dev/apache2.conf_*
    IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/conf.d/*.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

My guess is that, redirection is failing, so content of angular application is either served directly from nginx as defined in its domains configuration. I am working on it and updating here as it goes

Comment: There's no reverse proxy in the Nginx configuration shown here, but it redirects HTTPS to HTTP, which should not be desired. Instead, you need two reverse proxy configurations for each of the backend servers.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I don't understand, in first nginx server block , I have two proxy_pass section where I am passing redirected https traffic to http apache servers

Comment: `0.0.0.0`  is not a valid IP. Use the correct target IP for your reverse proxy directive.

Comment: `where I am passing redirected https traffic to http apache servers` - no. You are redirecting https to http, your proxy configuration is in the http block.

Comment: Enable logs and see if that gives you more info

Answer (score 1):

The most common use case for a Nginx proxy in this kind of setup would be providing the TLS termination and preventing clients from using the unencrypted backend services directly.

[image: Sequence diagram]

The Nginx configuration for this would have:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8085/api/;
    }
}
```

Then, for increased security, both the Apache and the Spring Boot would be listening on the local loopback instead of the public IP address.

- Apache:

  ```
  Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
      # Directives
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Spring Boot:

  ```
  server.address=127.0.0.1
  server.port=8085
  ```

Furthermore, it is best to serve any static files directly with Nginx.